# How to identify the position of a sequence of elements in an array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, patch, element

I'm learning bash and I'm trying identify a sequence elements (patch or subarray) position into a array.
For example:

```
array=(9 5 8 3 2 7 5 9 0 1 1 5 4 3 8 9 6 2 6 5 7 9 8);
patch=(0 1 1 5)
```

I would like to obtain a output equals to 8 (start position of my patch in relation to array) or 11 (final position).

Answer (score 1):

`bash` doesn't really have any built-in facility to do this; you need to walk the array yourself:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do

  for ((j=0; j<${#patch[@]}; j++)); do
    # Make sure the corresponding elements
    # match, or give up. RHS is quoted to ensure
    # actual string equality, rather than just pattern matching
    [[ ${array[i+j] == "${patch[j]}" ]] || break
  done

  if [[ $j == ${#patch[@] ]]; then
      # All the comparisons succeeded!
      start=$i
      finish=$((i+j-1))
      break
  fi
done
```